# Hide/show an element by using HTML attribute as condition in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-directive

I have one `ng-template` that is being reused as table headers.

```
<ng-template
  let-table="table"
  let-column="column"
  let-label="label"
  #tableHeaderTemplate
>
  <th [appSort]="table" sort-order="" [attr.sort-key]="column">
    <div>
      <span>{{ label }}</span>
      <span> (asc) </span>
      <span> (desc) </span>
    </div>
  </th>
</ng-template>
```

On clicking of the column header the table's data is sorted.
I need to show `(asc)` or `(desc)` besides the column based on the attribute `sort-order`.

Check sample of my code below :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ijcuy3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Does [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-54shwe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) fit your requirement? I marked the header with `#header` and then test if the attriubute has a specific value.

Comment: Thank you kind sir. That sure looks like a solution. 
Could you tell me how does it not confuse with other header elements that may have same #header attribute added ?

Comment: The variables are block-scoped within the `ng-template`, which means you don't have to worry about duplicate variable declarations. You should however, extract the logic in a angular pipe so that `getAttribute()` does not need to be called within the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[hidden]** attribute to hide your element and get  value of *sort-key* attr by specifying an Identifier to your table header.

```
  <th #tableHeader [appSort]="table" sort-order="" [attr.sort-key]="column">
    <div>
      <span>{{ label }}</span>
      <span [hidden]="tableHeader.getAttribute('sort-order') !== 'asc'"> (asc) </span>
      <span [hidden]="tableHeader.getAttribute('sort-order') !== 'desc'"> (desc) </span>
    </div>
  </th>
</ng-template>
```